# Why sequelize can not call increment without an instance?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

According to official doc [Incrementing certain values of an instance](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#incrementing-certain-values-of-an-instance).

We can increment values of an instance.

But why can not we call `increment` by `Sequelize` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an Instance's method and not a model's method.

You can use something like :

```
someModel.update( { clicks : sequelize.literal( "clicks + 1" ) } ) )
```

if you want to increment all instances in a model.

Comment: Yes, I know it'a an Instance's method. Your method is what I want, but why  not create an function called `someModel.increment(values, options)`? I think it's in common used. 